# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str getting this error while creating port listen

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, string-formatting

Why I am getting this error when I have copied the correct code from google How to solve this error.

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)
print("[-#-]  Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_port, bind_ip))

# this is our clint-hanadaling thread


def handle_client(client_socket):
    # print out what client sends
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("[* ] Received %s " % request)
    # send back a request
    client_socket.send("ACK!")
    client_socket.close()
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print("[*] Accepted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))
        # spin up our client thread  to handle incoming data
        clinet_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=client)
        clinet_handler.start()
```

> Getting error at: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:/Users/Najuser/Desktop/PYThon/tcp.py", line 10, in 
> print("[-#-]  Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_port, bind_ip)) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print("[-#-]  Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_port, bind_ip))
```

to

```
print("[-#-]  Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port))
```

The string formatters `%d` was expecting a number, however `bind_ip` was a string. The values to be printed were in the wrong order

Comment: @ggordin one question why it is only listening but not sending any response from the client

Comment: Try unindenting starting from the line with `while True:`. The while loop should not be in the `handle_client` function. This function is called when a new client connects to the server.